# i want to end set interval function after my count down reach 0

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have want to end setinterval function after my timer reach 0
i am getting time from timeout.php in tout variable

this is code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">


    var inter =setInterval(function()
    {
        var xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","timeout.php",false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        var tout= xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = tout;
    },1000);

    if(tout=0)
    {
        clearInterval(inter);
    }

</script>
```

here is my timeout.php which send time to above code in tout variable and setinterval work as repeat function

```
<?php

session_start();
extract($_POST);

include('database.php');

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');


$from_time1=date('H:i:s');

$to_time1=$_SESSION["end_time"];

$timefirst=strtotime($from_time1);

$timesecond=strtotime($to_time1);

$diffrenceinseconds=$timesecond-$timefirst;


 $rem = gmdate("H:i:s",$diffrenceinseconds);

 $_SESSION["rem"]=$rem; 
echo $rem;

$inter=$_SESSION["inter"];

if($diffrenceinseconds==0)
{          
if($submit=='Get Result' && isset($ans)) 
        { //php code for the page to run
    }
?>
```

Comment: yes i was looking for where to write  .. well its not working timer still continue  even after reaching 00:00:00

Comment: i am sorry i did not downvote you ans

Comment: yes i am checking

Comment: its not working the timer still continue after it reach 00 to 23:00:00..... will it be help if i provide timeout.php code

Comment: here i added the code for timeout.php

Comment: yes yes i will bro  let me get the ans first plz

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">


var inter =setInterval(function()
 {
    var xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","timeout.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    var tout= xmlhttp.responseText;
    
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML =tout;
},1000);

if(tout==0)
{
    return false;
}

</script>
```

I think you should use double equal in your condition.

Hope this will help.
Thanks;

here a code for a timer

```html
<?php
 $com = trim($_SESSION["end_time"]);
  $now = date(" H:i:s") ;
 
 $dteStart = new DateTime($com);
   $dteEnd   = new DateTime($now);
 $dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);

 
  
  
  print $dteDiff->format("%H:%I:%S"); 
?>
```

this code should work you need to put in your timeout.php

Comment: maybe it's a problem with data you get with innerhtml

Comment: var tou= xmlhttp.responseText;
    var tout= tou.trim();

Comment: can i use stop() insted

Comment: and with the return false?

Comment: nothing is working the time reach 00:00:00 and code run for page but then timer continue again to 23 hours